# AutoIncrement primary key in subclass of Room model

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I have a class `Model`

```
public abstract class Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public String id;
}
```

and sub-class `FooModel`

```
@Entity
public FooModel extends Model {
    String name;
}
```

I'd like to mark `id` as autoincrement but only in the child `FooModel` using `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my understanding room just as most other ORM frameworks does not realy handle class inheritance very well. you may consider defining your two classes as separate models in order to maximise on the full functionality of room .

Comment: In my case, a String primary key can not be auto incremented anyway.

Comment: yeah sure string can not be auto incremented